# Android 4.4 hide navbar/statusbar using Accessibility service & service

Tags: android, service, accessibility, statusbar, navbar

I have implemented some features by integrating accessibility service for my application.

I currently have a 'system overlay' ImageView that can detect TouchEvent's. however i have seen it done that immersive mode, hiding the statusbar or navbar is possible without root.

i need to beable to ***access the view of my touch detection window*** in order to process any accessibility

**My Accessibility service contains:**

```
     ...
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected() {
            serviceInstance = this;
        }
    ...
```

**my touch detector:**

```
  ...
        WindowManager wm;
        private MyAccessibilityService myAccessibilityService;
        private ImageView mTouchDetector;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

            super.onCreate();

            myAccessibilityService = MyAccessibilityService.getSharedInstance();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    100,
                    100,
                    0, 0,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, debugMode());
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
            wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(mTouchDetector, params);
    }
...
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "however i have seen it done that immersive mode, hiding the statusbar or navbar is possible without root"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Using an accessibility service, hide the system ui globally. To enable full use of the entire screen on nexus devices. My app does not have an activity that sits on the foreground its a service with a 'system overlay'

Comment: it must be because immersive mode app on the play store does it using a service without root!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have partially solved this problem, however having some trouble with the back button, check here to see if it gets resolved.

create the service as normal but add these flags to the overlay:

**to the window manager:**

> TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE,                FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
>   FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL

**to the view:**

> int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
>   FloatingView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

**[Android floating window with hidden statusbar Accessibility problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608475/android-floating-window-with-hidden-statusbar-accessibility-problems)**

Comment: Thanks it works, i guess i should keep following the thread to get the final solution.

Comment: Did anyone find a way to make back button working too?

Comment: It works but the keyboard and the back button is not accessible. Any fix for this?