# Android floating window with hidden statusbar Accessibility problems

Tags: android, accessibility, android-4.4-kitkat, android-fullscreen

I am working on android 4.4.2 building an application with a system overlay/floating window created by an accessibility service.

Edit:**I want to be able to hide the status bar GLOBALLY (in any app)** (made possible by the code below) however when the overlay is shown i stop receiving acessibilityEvents from the listener and the software/hardware back button
When the floating view is injected into windowmanager:

1. **AccessibilityEvent listener does not receive updates**
2. **Soft/hardware back key does not register (home/recents does)**

in order to hide the status bar both ***'FLAG_FULLSCREEN | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL'*** are needed to allow touching the rest of the screen and ***'View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN'*** allows

**Accessibility Service (on connected method) :**

```
  @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        serviceInstance = this;
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        FloatingView = new View(this);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                0, 0,
                0, 0,
                TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE,
                FLAG_FULLSCREEN | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
        params.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Toast;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;

            windowManager.addView(FloatingView, params);

 int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
  FloatingView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        }
```

**Accessibility Service (on connected method) :**

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Log.i("","Just log me some rubbish");

}
```

**My AccessibilitySetup.xml:**

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="0"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/notification_description"
    />
```

Comment: thanks @SainathPatwarykarnate i cannot use the flag NOT_FOCUSABLE because it does not allow me to hide the statusbar within any application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours and a week of research i found theres is no way to do both of these due to security restrictions. i will implmenet these features in the root mode of my app.

the workaround i am using is a simple button that revives the system ui and removes the view that is blocking the accessibility input

Answer (score 3):

Hey i think this would work!!!!

You just need to set WindowManager.LayoutParams height width property correctly.
By this you can able to receiving acessibilityEvents from the listener and the software/hardware back button.

Try this

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            // this is to enable the notification to receive touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = retrieveStatusBarHeight(context);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
    StatusBarOverlayView view = new StatusBarOverlayView(context);
    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);

public static int retrieveStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: cannot find the class StatusBarOverlayView